# Remove the moved site property from google search console

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

In Google Search Console, I have performed a redirect from the old domain to the new domain using the "Change of Address Tool" in google console.

The redirect has been done in the `.haccess` file as well as a `Goole console` for 3 months ago and everything is working properly.

My question is S**hould I remove this old domain property from the search console?** or I must leave it forever?

I am afraid, it may consume my budget crawl for other properties on the same domain!

Comment: Why do you think you're crawled budget is tied to what is in Google search console?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for your reply, to be honest, I don't know! I just thinking about don't hard the google crawl bot, I have noted that my site rank has been dropped after it moved to a new domain, I am trying to learn and read about how I get my posts crawled and indexed faster and get back my old rank! so I thought I should let search console only concentrate to may main property instead of all old properties! hope you got my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's recommendation appears in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9370220?hl=en) for the Change Of Address tool:

> Maintain the redirects for at least 180 days--longer if you still see any traffic to them from Google Search. Remove your old pages, but we recommend continuing to pay for the old domain for at least a year to prevent others from buying and using your abandoned domain for malicious purposes. *After the 180 day period, Google does not recognize any relationship between the old and new sites,* and treats the old site as an unrelated site, if still present and crawlable.

(Emphasis in the above quote is mine.)

So, make sure it's present for at least 180 days, and then feel free to remove it if you wish.

Your crawl budget shouldn't be affected by the site you moved from, if as you said you implemented it correctly and it's working. Once Google notes the 301 redirects, it will start to crawl and index your new site, and drop the old pages from the index.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, you said "drop the old pages from the index." did you mean the ranked page from the old domain will be dropped and will not be replaced with the corresponding redirect URL from the new site!

Comment: The opposite - the old page that 301 redirects to the new page will be dropped eventually, and the new page will enter the search index instead. If you saw an overall drop in rankings for the new domain, this is common at first. Once Google notes your 301's, and the activity on your new domain (new posts, etc.), the domain should rise in rankings.

Comment: I have moved to the new domain for 4 months and still facing rank drop! is it normal? I performed the redirect and changed the post URL from *olddomain/postdate/title* to *newdomain/title* do you think changing permalinks will drop my rank

Comment: It's not the permalinks, as long as the 301 redirects are implemented correctly on all of them. Something else is going on. I would recommend going through Search Console to see if anything looks weird. Also, learn and download an SEO tool, like Screaming Frog and Moz, to see what's going on with your site from a technical SEO perspective and from your link profile. Run some audits. You'll probably find something you can fix or update.